# problem from PDEs, H. Brezis

Tags: sobolev-spaces

today I read book Sobolev space, PDEs of H.Brezis, and when I read chapter 8, I don't know why following remark is easy:

**Remark 11 (page 214).** Let $I$ be a bounded interval, let $1\leq p\leq \infty$, and et $1\leq q\leq \infty$, then

$$|||u|||=||u'||_p+||u||_q$$

is equivalent to the norm of $W^{1,p}(I)$.

I know $$||u||_{W^{1,p}(I)}=||u||_p+||u'||_p$$
By Sobolev embedding: there exists a constant $C$ such that $$||u||_q=\left(\int_I |u|^q\right)^\frac{1}{q}\leq \left(\int_I ||u||_\infty^q\right)^\frac{1}{q}=I^\frac{1}{q} ||u||_\infty\leq CI^\frac{1}{q} ||u||_{W^{1,p}(I)}$$
and
$$||u'||_p\leq ||u||_{W^{1,p}(I)}$$
so
$$|||u|||=||u'||_p+||u||_q\leq (CI^\frac{1}{q} +1) ||u||_{W^{1,p}(I)}$$

But I can't find $\alpha$ such that
$$|||u|||\geq \alpha ||u||_{W^{1,p}(I)}$$
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can (for example) consider two cases:

Case 1 - $q> p$

We have that $\|u\|_p^p=\int_I |u|^p$. Because $q>p$, we have that $\frac{q}{p}>1$, hence we can apply Holder inequality, to conclude that $\|u\|_p^p\leq C \|u\|_q^{p}$, where $C>0$ is a positive constant (that can change in every line). From it we have that $\|u\|_{1,p}=\|u\|_p+\|u'\|_p\leq C\|u\|_q+\|u'\|_p\leq C\||u\||$

Case 2- $q\leq p$

In this case $W^{1,p}(I)$ is embedded in $W^{1,q}(I)$, hence $\|u\|_p=\Big(\int_I|u|^p\Big)^{1/p}\leq C\|u\|_\infty\leq C\|u\|_{1,q}$. From here you can conclude.

Comment: Can you explain more case 2?

Comment: Sure. Note that you can compare $\|u'\|_q$ with $\|u'\|_p$ because $q\leq p$, so you have that $\|u\|_{1,q}=\|u\|_q+\|u'\|_q\leq C(\|u\|_q+\|u'\|_p)$. Can you finish now?